# tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy doesn't work for me, and strange things happen

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Tensorflow: 2.9.0
Python: 3.8.10

I see many toturs use distribution is much faster than only one GPU, to accelarate training, I change my code to training across multiple processing units, GPU0 and GPU1 on one machine.
However, after using `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()`, training failed in only batch with nan values.

Here is the code i use model.fit

```
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=["/gpu:0", "/gpu:1"])
print('Number of devices: %d' % strategy.num_replicas_in_sync)

with strategy.scope(): 
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=(64,64,1))
    model = MyModel()
    outputs = model(inputs)
    model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

    model.summary() 
        
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss=loss_fn)

    EPOCHS = 12
    train_dataset, val_dataset = load_data(1, 10)
    model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=20)
```

Here is the code I use custom training loop:

```
with strategy.scope():  
    optimizer= keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
    def loss_fn(real, model_out):
            #MSE
            pass

    inputs = keras.Input(shape=(64,64,1))
    model = MyModel()
    outputs = model(inputs)
    model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

    model.summary()

def train_step(inputs):
    x_batch_train, y_batch_train = inputs
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        logits = model(x_batch_train, training=True)
        loss = loss_fn(y_batch_train, logits)
        loss = tf.nn.compute_average_loss(loss)
        

    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

    return loss 

def distributed_train_epoch(dataset):
    total_loss = 0.0
    num_batches = 0
    for x in dataset:
        per_replica_losses = strategy.run(train_step, args=(x,))
        total_loss += strategy.reduce(
                tf.distribute.ReduceOp.SUM, per_replica_losses, axis=None)
        num_batches += 1
    return total_loss / tf.cast(num_batches, dtype=tf.float32)

epochs = 2000
for epoch in range(0, epochs):
    
    print("\nStart of epoch %d" % (epoch,))
    start_time = time.time()
    
    dataset_idx = (epoch % 9) + 1
    batch_size = 15
    train_dataset, val_dataset = load_data(dataset_idx, batch_size)

    train_dist_dataset = strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset(train_dataset)
    val_dist_dataset = strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset(val_dataset)


    train_loss = distributed_train_epoch(train_dist_dataset)
```

Here [Training on Multiple GPUs causes NaN Validation Errors in Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54283937/training-on-multiple-gpus-causes-nan-validation-errors-in-keras) Woodshop solve this problem by setting batch_size meet this condition: **nelements / ngpus / batch_size == 0**, however it doesn't work for me, I print every batch_size there isn't None batch.

Than, I try to specify which GPU to use:  `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=["/gpu:0"])` or `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=["/gpu:1"])` both can successfully train the model, here are what nvidia-smi printout[tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=["/gpu:0"]), only GPU1 is running(Memory-Usage)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVZjV.png)
[tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=["/gpu:1"]), why GPU0 running in addition to GPU1??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s83rp.png)

if I specify `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=["/gpu:0","/gpu:1"])` can get nan loss value.

is ths a bug in Tensorflow or my code is wrong?